# How to limit choices for pydantic using Enum

Tags: python, enums, pydantic

I got next Enum options:

```
class ModeEnum(str, Enum):
""" mode """

    map = "map"
    cluster = "cluster"
    region = "region"
```

This enum used in two Pydantic data structures.
In one data structure I need all Enum options.
In other data structure I need to exclude `region`.
If I use custom validation for this and try to enter some `other` value, standard Validation error message informs, that allowed values are all three.

So what is best decision in this situation?

P.S.
I use `map` variable in `ModeEnum`. Is it bad? I can't imagine situation when it can override built-in `map` object, but still, is it ok?

Comment: in practice it is bad to override built-in variables, rename it to `map_` or something of the like

Comment: Your `map` member is not in the global name space, and not overriding the `map` builtin, so there is no issue with using that name.  In general, overriding built-in names is fine, particularly if you don't use the built-in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little bit of a hack, but if you mark your validator with [`pre=True`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/#pre-and-per-item-validators), you should be able to force it to run first, and then you can throw a custom error with the allowed values.

Comment: Thx. I see that there is no simple decisions. It seems that it will be more clear make two separate Enum classes.